# confused about Circom LessThan implementation

Tags: bit-manipulation, circom

I am trying to implement a LessThan template which outputs 1 if y is less than x and 0 is x is more than y. Below is the sample code from the circom library and I am trying to understand whats going on this code below.

```
template LessThan(n) {
    assert(n <= 252);
    signal input in[2];
    signal output out;

    component n2b = Num2Bits(n+1);

    n2b.in <== in[0]+ (1<<n) - in[1];

    out <== 1-n2b.out[n];
}
```

i dont whats going on in:

```
n2b.in <== in[0]+ (1<<n) - in[1];
```

it involves some bitwise operation.

Answer (score 2):

Since `in[0] < in[1]` is not a quadratic expression we have to rewrite the condition a bit to be able to express it as a constraint. The key idea here is to see that `in[0] < in[1]` is equivalent to `in[0] - in[1] < 0`. Adding `2^n` to both sides we get `2^n + in[0] - in[1] < 2^n`.

Now, `2^n = (1 << n)` which is where the expression `in[0] + (1 << n) - in[1]` comes from. The final constraint simply ensures that `out = 1` if and only if bit `n` of `2^n + in[0] - in[1]` is 0, which happens exactly when `2^n + in[0] - in[1] < 2^n`.

Comment: this assumes that `in[0]` and `in[1]` are n-bit numbers

Comment: lol, 3 hours later I discover this https://blog.trailofbits.com/2023/03/21/circomspect-static-analyzer-circom-more-passes/ and apparently this led to bugs :D